# How to add row which is having multiple column dynamically in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

Hi I have developed the UI like the screen below.Now I want to add the last row in the UI on last plus button click event.

I know how to add `Button` or `EditText` dynamically but I am not getting how can I add and delete row which is having multiple column dynamically.

**Edit:-** One Important thing about last row is each column is editable.That means I need the reference of each column for getting it's content.When I am adding row dynamically plus button should get placed in new row.Similarly if I remove row row plus button should get shifted to the upper row.

How can I do this.Any guideline or any approach will be appreciated.

[image]
This is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/navi_bar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/title_bar_btnBack"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_button_image" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/title_bar_btnExport"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title_bar_btnBack"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/export_button_normal" />

<!-- Create PDF Part 2 -->


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pdf_Upper_Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_bar_btnBack"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_bg_part1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pdf_Upper_Image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Kassenbuch"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Name :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Akshay"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<!-- Custom Pdf Part 2 -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pdf_Upper_Image"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_bg_part2" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:text="Einnahmen"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtName"
    android:text="Month :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:text="Mand Nr. :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMand"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="Mand"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="05"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9" 
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtYear"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtMonth"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_bar_btnExport"
    android:text="Year :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:text="Blatt :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtYear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtMonth"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_bar_btnExport"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtMonth"
    android:text="2012"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Ausgabne"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:text="Bestand"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtMand"
    android:text="Datum"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="Beleg Konto"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_marginRight="03dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView13"
    android:text="Gegen Konto"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="08dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:text="Anfangsbestand/Ubertrag"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="9dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
    android:text="USt satz."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="09dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtBlatt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
    android:text="Blatt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9" />

<include android:id="@+id/firstRow"
     layout="@layout/custom_pdf3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pdf_Middle_Image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying lot of different things I solved my problem like below.I made certain changes in my xml.I used `LinearLayout` with `ScrollView`.

And I created one xml file which is having complete row.Now my task is to add that xml in the `LinearLayout` which I did in the following manner.I am calling this method on button click event at each time.

```
     public void AddDynamicView() {

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.show_pdfTableLayout);

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pdf3, null);

    linearLayout.addView(view);
    list.add(view);  // Here I have created list of View so that I can get the id of specific view.
          }
```

I have tried this with `TableLayout` but I was having some issue with occupying whole row.That's why I had used `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a layout that represents a complete row,then you can use:

`public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)` from `LayoutInflater`(a class in `android.view` package) to Inflate a **`new view hierarchy`** from the specified XML resource(for example your new row).

Now you can add this view(your row) dynamically to your main layout with a specific tag(like adding a button dynamically to the layout).

Comment: Thanks for the replay I will try this.But I have one issue how can I get the reference of each `EditText` in that row.

Comment: @Akshay Please tell me if it is true.

Comment: +1 for your answer.I got some idea from your answer.Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an XML layout file, which will represent a 'row in the list view.
2. Implement a custom Adapter, using base Adapter.
3. In the `getView()` method, Inflate the Xml layout, Reference the inner items (using `outerLayout.findViewById()`, set `Listeners` right there, and Finally `return` the `view`.
4. Write the implementation for your listener.

Simple enough? :-)

Comment: that means I should use listview for this.But I don't want any changes in my UI.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the whole layout at runtime. Create a single row containgin all ur columns and set visibility of the last one to gone. Change the visibility when the plus button is pressed.
Creating a row of type Relative layout will be good i think. When u want to remove a row Then you will have to count the Relative layouts in the main layout and then remove the index which  u want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand best through an example. Lets simplify things a little bit. Lets say your main layout is this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout" >

</TableLayout>
```

It's a simple `TableLayout` without any views yet (You could have pre-baked rows in it). Now you want to create `TableRows` wich you want to add dinamically, and handle it's subviews separately, right? You could create your whole `TableRow` in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow_textview"
        android:text="Hello" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow_button"
        android:text="World" />
</TableRow>
```

Then the java part. Lets say you want to add 10 of those rows to your TableLayout, and handle each rows button and separately. You can do it like this (You must have access to a Context object):

```
// get the main TableLayout from xml
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);  

// get a LayoutInflater object. 'this' is the current Activity
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    //Create an inflated instance of that layout
    TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);

    //Notice, that we call the findViewById() function on the previously 
    //inflated layout, which means, that we can only access its subviews
    Button rowButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.tablerow_button);
    TextView rowText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tablerow_textview);

    //Now that you have those Views, you can do whatever you want with them, (set
    an onClickListener, change the text, etc)

    //finally we need to add the row to the table
    layout.addView(row);
}
```

It would also be a good idea if you wrapper created a class for your inflated layout, with its own getter-setter functions, and you could just instantiate it with the new operator, and all the inflation would be done in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with [custom views.](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) Then each view can be a complex view and you can do what ever you wish, this task should not be easy.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Name :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#3EC7F9"
    android:textSize="12dp" />

<com.sample.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then `MyCustomView` can be Linear Layout or what ever.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want to say can you please suggest me some link or more information

Answer (score 0):

In above xml

**you did all the things in Textview and adjust that**

instead of using that you have to create a `Tablelayout` in your xml file.

onButtonClick event you have to create a new tablerow dynamically then add components by using `tablerow.addview(componentsname)` and finally add tablerow to tablelayout

[Simple TableLayout](http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/)

Comment: I had already tried it.But the thing is that table row is having some issue while adding rows it is not occupying whole row.

Comment: it can occupying the whole row by adjusting size of components

Answer (score 0):

Probably I didn't understand well!!!

You can do everything mentioned in the question using ListView and Adapter.
You can provide an array to hold fields, feed an adapter with the array and feed listView with adapter.
If you need a new Row just add an element to the array.
If you want to delete a Row, just remove it from array.
If you want to sort items, just sort the array.
If you want to select prev/next, just use listview selection method.

I was wondered you checked your answer that is not absolutely correct approach. It's true but if your target ui is complex, the page will need a lot of time to render and scroll than ListViews that is dynamic and optimized.

If you think my answer sounds good, Let me know to update it with some code.